# Easiest way to remember selected dropdown position in PHP on Postback

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, foreach, postback, smarty

Note: I'm forced to use a TPL file. I've looked at the other solutions on this website and they don't seem to work for me. I know what option I want selected by using $_POST['book'].
I've already tried {html_options} (smarty) and nothing seems to work. All I want to do is remember the Dropdown list position when the user hits the submit (GO) button. What's the easiest way to implement this?

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
      $book = $_POST['book'];
      $chapter = $_POST['chapter'];
      $tbl_link = "PLD_LINK";

      $query_chapter = "SELECT `TITLE`,`SORT_ORD`, `DESCRIPTION` FROM $tbl_link WHERE `TITLE` LIKE '%$book%' && `SORT_ORD` = '$chapter'";
      $search_chapter=$db->query($query_chapter);
      while($row = $search_chapter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      { $coal[] = $row; }
      $tpl->assign('coal', $coal);                       
                                                             }
      $search_chapter->closeCursor();
    }
?>
<?php
while($rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
{ $results[] = $rows ; }
$tpl->assign('results', $results);
}
?>
```

.TPL:

```
<select name='book'>
{foreach item=rows from=$results}
<option value='{$rows.TITLE}'>{$rows.TITLE}</option>{/foreach}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your template file

```
<select name='book'>
{foreach item=rows from=$results}
<option value='{$rows.TITLE}'{if isset($book) && $rows.TITLE == $book} selected{/if}>{$rows.TITLE}</option>{/foreach}
</select>
```

and assign the `$value` in your php file

```
$tpl->assign("book", $book);
```